# Clarification of the BibLaTeX location field for patent entries

Tags: biblatex

The [BibLaTeX manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), in  §2.2.2, clarifies the use of the `location` field for `@Patent` entries:

> With @patent entries, this list indicates the scope of a patent.

Could anyone elaborate upon the intended use of this field, in practice?

Is it not self-evident that a US patent has scope (at least) within the US, and international scope wherever bilateral IP policies exist?

Perhaps this field should be modified to permit the encoding of useful scope information, like the existence of joint filings or automatic propagation to other patent offices (e.g. the patent's status across the [IP5](https://www.fiveipoffices.org/about.html))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex`'s patent support is only rudimentary and to some extent even only illustrative of what is possible. If you need more advanced features, you will have to implement them yourself.

Specifically about `location` the documentation of the `@patent` type on p. 11 has

> Use the `type` field to specify the type and the `location` field to indicate the
>   scope of the patent, if different from the scope implied by the `type`.

So I would say that `location` is usually not needed if `type` (or maybe even `number`) already implies the scope (US patent, UK patent, German patent, ...). There is only one example of `location` with `@patent` in `biblatex-examples.bib`

```
@patent{almendro,
  author       = {Almendro, Jos{\'e} L. and Mart{\'i}n, Jacinto and S{\'a}nchez,
                  Alberto and Nozal, Fernando},
  title        = {Elektromagnetisches Signalhorn},
  number       = {EU-29702195U},
  date         = 1998,
  location     = {countryfr and countryuk and countryde},
}
```

and that is a fake entry which does not exist, so inferences as to what exactly things should mean are risky. According to http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2007-01/msg00188.html and http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2007-01/msg00227.html the `location` here was intended to show that an initially German patent was somehow extended to other countries as well. Whether or not that is common usage or important I don't know.

[This post by Philipp Lehman (and the entire thread) on `comp.text.tex` about the `@patent` entry type](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2007-01/msg00321.html) are interesting for historical purposes.